# Split text to phrases and enumerate them

Tags: python, sequencing

I have this sequence:

```
>my_sequence
atccagcaaaaacgctccaaggattctcgactggactcattacttaatcagtattcgcaagcggacgccgaggtcgtaaaggctgaaaccgcacaatcggatgcgcccagtgatgacgcactxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcgccttgcccacccaccgacaaccggtgagtgaaaaattggaacggtgattaaaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxttgtgctttatttctggagggcggtgtttaggggtaggcgcgccatgttttttgccttcagcgatcccaggtacaaccagtccccatattcgcgcactgtcgtgatcggcgagtaattacctgtgctcgcatcttgcaggttggcaatcaccttgccgtccaagtccagacccagtgcaaaggcacgcttttccatgggtttgggcagtaccgtcaatgcccgaacaatcattttgc
```

I want to split this long sequence eliminating the "xxxxx" and create separated sequences like this:

```
>1
atccagcaaaaacgctccaaggattctcgactggactcattacttaatcagtattcgcaagcggacgccgaggtcgtaaaggctgaaaccgcacaatcggatgcgcccagtgatgacgcact
>2
cgccttgcccacccaccgacaaccggtgagtgaaaaattggaacggtgattaaa  
>3
ttgtgctttatttctggagggcggtgtttaggggtaggcgcgccatgttttttgccttcagcgatcccaggtacaaccagtccccatattcgcgcactgtcgtgatcggcgagtaattacctgtgctcgcatcttgcaggttggcaatcaccttgccgtccaagtccagacccagtgcaaaggcacgcttttccatgggtttgggcagtaccgtcaatgcccgaacaatcattttgc
```

Does anyone have any idea to start?

Thank you.

Comment: 1st step: `biopython` for parser fasta file. It's a good way

Comment: 2nd step: use `split` function or `regex`

Comment: 3rd step, use `biopython` for save and format output

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. How about putting all those steps in an answer?

Comment: @Ev.Kounis the question is `Does anyone have any idea to start?` .... It's not like finishing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple way would be to first split on each "x" character, and then filter out the empty results:

```
sequences = filter(None, my_sequence.split("x"))
```

Here, the `None` argument to filter means to only keep truthy-values – empty strings are treated as `false`, so they will be removed from the results.

Note: In Python 3, `filter` returns an iterator so if you want a list, use:

```
sequences = list(filter(None, my_sequence.split("x")))
```

For example:

```
In [5]: filter(str, my_sequence.split("x"))
Out[5]: 
['atccagcaaaaacgctccaaggattctcgactggactcattacttaatcagtattcgcaagcggacgccgaggtcgtaaaggctgaaaccgcacaatcggatgcgcccagtgatgacgcact',
 'cgccttgcccacccaccgacaaccggtgagtgaaaaattggaacggtgattaaa',
 'ttgtgctttatttctggagggcggtgtttaggggtaggcgcgccatgttttttgccttcagcgatcccaggtacaaccagtccccatattcgcgcactgtcgtgatcggcgagtaattacctgtgctcgcatcttgcaggttggcaatcaccttgccgtccaagtccagacccagtgcaaaggcacgcttttccatgggtttgggcagtaccgtcaatgcccgaacaatcattttgc']
```

---

Another solution is to use regular expressions. If you have a variable amount of "x" characters between the sequences, you can split on the `x+` pattern, which matches one or more x's in a row.

For example:

```
In [6]: import re
In [7]: p = re.compile(r'x+')
In [8]: p.split(my_sequence)
Out[8]: 
['atccagcaaaaacgctccaaggattctcgactggactcattacttaatcagtattcgcaagcggacgccgaggtcgtaaaggctgaaaccgcacaatcggatgcgcccagtgatgacgcact',
 'cgccttgcccacccaccgacaaccggtgagtgaaaaattggaacggtgattaaa',
 'ttgtgctttatttctggagggcggtgtttaggggtaggcgcgccatgttttttgccttcagcgatcccaggtacaaccagtccccatattcgcgcactgtcgtgatcggcgagtaattacctgtgctcgcatcttgcaggttggcaatcaccttgccgtccaagtccagacccagtgcaaaggcacgcttttccatgggtttgggcagtaccgtcaatgcccgaacaatcattttgc']
```

Comment: can you cast that to `list` for Python 3 users?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have a single entry for each sequence of x-s you can use regular expressions:

```
import re
x = 'atccagcaaaaacgctccaaggattctcgactggactcattacttaatcagtattcgcaagcggacgccgaggtcgtaaaggctgaaaccgcacaatcggatgcgcccagtgatgacgcactxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxcgccttgcccacccaccgacaaccggtgagtgaaaaattggaacggtgattaaaxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxttgtgctttatttctggagggcggtgtttaggggtaggcgcgccatgttttttgccttcagcgatcccaggtacaaccagtccccatattcgcgcactgtcgtgatcggcgagtaattacctgtgctcgcatcttgcaggttggcaatcaccttgccgtccaagtcc
agacccagtgcaaaggcacgcttttccatgggtttgggcagtaccgtcaatgcccgaacaatcattttgc'
re.split(r'x+', x)
>['atccagcaaaaacgctccaaggattctcgactggactcattacttaatcagtattcgcaagcggacgccgaggtcgtaaaggctgaaaccgcacaatcggatgcgcccagtgatgacgcact',
 'cgccttgcccacccaccgacaaccggtgagtgaaaaattggaacggtgattaaa',
 'ttgtgctttatttctggagggcggtgtttaggggtaggcgcgccatgttttttgccttcagcgatcccaggtacaaccagtccccatattcgcgcactgtcgtgatcggcgagtaattacctgtgctcgcatcttgcaggttggcaatcaccttgccgtccaagtccagacccagtgcaaaggcacgcttttccatgggtttgggcagtaccgtcaatgcccgaacaatcattttgc']
```

Here `r'x+'` means I will split the original string on a sequence of one or more x-s.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to have the desired output is using `list comprehension`.

This is an example:

```
# Or maybe a generator
# data = (k for k in my_sequence.split("x") if k)
data = [k for k in my_sequence.split("x") if k]

for k,v in enumerate(data):
    print("{0} >>> {1}".format(k,v))
```

Output:

```
0 >>> atccagcaaaaacgctccaaggattctcgactggactcattacttaatcagtattcgcaagcggacgccgaggtcgtaaaggctgaaaccgcacaatcggatgcgcccagtgatgacgcact
1 >>> cgccttgcccacccaccgacaaccggtgagtgaaaaattggaacggtgattaaa
2 >>> ttgtgctttatttctggagggcggtgtttaggggtaggcgcgccatgttttttgccttcagcgatcccaggtacaaccagtccccatattcgcgcactgtcgtgatcggcgagtaattacctgtgctcgcatcttgcaggttggcaatcaccttgccgtccaagtccagacccagtgcaaaggcacgcttttccatgggtttgggcagtaccgtcaatgcccgaacaatcattttgc
```